# unreported exception must be caught or declared to be thrown in static initializer

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
class C {
    private static final Object myObject = makeObject(); // *

    private static Object makeObject() throws IOException {
        try {
           ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ...
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get exception in line marked with `*`:

```
error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

How to declare the exception to be thrown in this case? I know I can catch it, my question is about the syntax.

Comment: Have you tried static{...} block?

Comment: yes, I get a similar error.

Comment: You can put a `try/catch` block inside a static initialiser block, and catch the `IOException`. I think that's as close as you can get. You cannot declare it thrown, in this case.

Comment: what is your goal - would you want class initialization to fail when an exception would be thrown?

Comment: Why are you catching and throwing same exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep the signature of `makeObject()` throwing `IOException`, you must do it this way:

```
class C {
    private static final Object myObject;

    static {
        try {
            myObject = makeObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static Object makeObject() throws IOException {
        try {
           ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ...
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

It is not allowed to throw a checked exception from a method that initializes a (static) field or within a static block. But it is allowed to throw an unchecked (runtime) exception. So you must catch your `IOException` and wrap it in a (subclass of) `RuntimeException`.

Alternatively, you can just not throw `IOException from`makeObject()` by doing the wrapping there:

```
class C {
    private static final Object myObject = makeObject(); // OK now

    private static Object makeObject() { // no 'throws'
        try {
           ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ...
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // wrap here
        }
    }
}
```

`IOException` is a checked exception which is forbidden by the Java Language Specification to be (potentially) thrown in a class variable initializer or static initializer (see [JLS §11.2.3. Exception Checking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3)):

> It is a compile-time error if a class variable initializer (§8.3.2) or static initializer (§8.7) of a named class or interface can throw a checked exception class.

This limitation does not apply to unchecked (runtime) exceptions.

Comment: thanks. could you explain why throwing a `RuntimeException` works but throwing `IOException` does not? I am new to Java..

Comment: @akonsu - I added a reference to JLS where this is specified as a rule. You might want to read up on checked vs. unchecked exceptions to get a better understanding of the differences.

Comment: static members are initialized before any instance of that class are created. Having an unprotected exception during static initialization could make the class unusable